# Variable type in Italics

Tags: java, netbeans

I am using the Outbound method from the jetty websocket package.

However the outbound variable name appears in italics in Netbeans. What does it mean? Should I avoid using this method?

This is how it appears in netbeans (I have put the italics in for clarity);

```
import org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.WebSocket.<i>Outbound</i>;

private <i>Outbound</i> mOutbound;
```

Comment: I don't know what italics mean in NetBeans but if it is like Eclipse it might indicate that `Outbound` is a static class inside `WebSocket`. Deprecated classes would normally be displayed struck trough.

Comment: I looked at the declaration of `WebSocket.Outbound`, it is an inner interface which is like a static inner class. However, the italics in NetBeans might also just indicate that `Outbound` is an interface, so nothing to worry about here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means the `Outbound` class is a static inner class, written inside the `WebSocket` class. The italics are here just to make this explicit to you. It doesn't mean you shouldn't use this class.

If Netbeans want to show you that you shouldn't use a class, method or attribute (for example, deprecated API), it will tell you so by crossing out part of the code.